# Toggling appendTo() using jQuery Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery

My .topics element relocates itself in the DOM -- and for testing purposes acquires the "active" class -- when the Waypoint triggers.

```
$('.navbar').waypoint(function() {
    $('.topics').toggleClass('active');
    $('.topics').appendTo( $('#menu') );
}, { offset: -50 });
```

When the waypoint is no longer in view the "active" class is removed from .topics as expected, yet the .topics elements remains appended to #menu.

Is it possible to restore .topics to its original DOM location by either toggling appendTo(); or triggering the event when the Waypoint becomes inactive?

Comment: "Waypoint"? A jQuery plugin presumably. Please provide a link.

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about - Snap, my bad... I should have specified it's a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting in an if statement to check if the element exists?

```
$('.navbar').waypoint(function() {
    $('.topics').toggleClass('active');
    if ($('#menu .topics').length) {
        $('#menu .topics').remove();
    } else {
        $('.topics').appendTo( $('#menu') );
    }
}, { offset: -50 });
```

Comment: A solid approach, but .topics remains appended to #menu when the waypoint's inactive. Are if/else statements rechecked when the waypoint becomes disabled?

Comment: Does .length mean if "#menu .topics" exists?

Comment: @rick Yes, it checks if it exists. If it doesn't work, I'm not sure what you want is achievable this way. However, you can always just toggle `.topics` to show/hide by adding `.toggle { display: none; } .toggle.active {display: block;}`.

Comment: I swapped $('#menu .topics').remove(); with $('.topics').appendTo( $('#orginialmenu') ); and that does the job. Thank you kindly. =)

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to steal @Banana's rep here but you will find it more efficient to avoid having to rediscover the `.topics` elements several times over, every time the handler fires. For example :

- assign the result of $('.topics') so it can be reused
- test `.hasClass('active')` rather than `$('#menu .topics').length`

If my understanding is correct, then this should give the same effect as your adaptation of Banana's code :

```
$('.navbar').waypoint(function() {
    var $topics = $('.topics').toggleClass('active');
    if($topics.hasClass('active')) {
        $topics.appendTo( $('#menu') );
    } else {
        $topics.appendTo( $('#orginialmenu') );
    }
}, { offset: -50 });
```

Performance optimisations like this can be important for the quality of your site/app's UI/UX, especially when the DOM is extensive.

Comment: Yo this is sweet! Thanks for following up with a more optimized approach. Greatly appreciated!